# Python script to connect to hosted database on Namecheap

Tags: python, mysql

**EDIT 1**

It looks like I can import the sqlite3 package.  Now I'm working on figuring out how to specify the IP address of the hosted server so I can connect to it.  It's not looking likely though.

---

**EDIT 2**

It looks like sqlite3 is not designed to access hosted databases.  The search continues.

---

This is a pretty basic question, however I haven't found any resources on Namecheap's website, here, or through Google searches that shed any light on my problem.  I'm trying to write a python script that will query my hosted database to retrieve records.  So far I haven't gotten past the first step of importing a module and this is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"

import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

import PyMySQL
```

cgitb works fine and prints out the following error message:

[image]

I also tried importing MySQLdb and received the same error.  Does anyone have experience with databases, python, and namecheap?

Comment: Is this code being run on your computer or on the server?

Comment: On the server.  Also, I think I found the issue.  I can successfully import sqlite3 so I'm trudging forward with that until I hit another road block.

Comment: The error means, that the module PyMySql wasn't installed in your server. Is your server a hosting or VPS?  Sqlite is stores the data in a file. It's not a real database server.

Comment: It's hosted using their value plan.  Would VPS allow me to install and use other packages like MySQLdb?